# Service does not call onCreate

Tags: java, android

i have created a Service and started it, but onCreate() never gets called. 
This is part of my TestService:

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    private static boolean isRunning = false;

   @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        isRunning = true;
    }
    ...
```

and this of my activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        startService(new Intent(this,TestService.class));
    }
```

and finally my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".TestService"></service>
</application>
```

startService gets called but a breakpoint in the onCreate of TestService never fires. Also isRunning is still false after startService

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: check is onStartCommand called?

Comment: are you added your service in Manifest.xml?

Comment: onStartCommand isn't called either, i have included my manifest

Answer (score 0):

From what I see everything looks fine and `onCreate()` is called always (as per [life cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm)). There are only two things I can think of:

1. Either your activity wasn't called or ran into an exception *or*

   `protected void onCreate(...)` (`protected`? → change to `public`)
2. the path `.` to your service is wrong in

   `<service android:name=".TestService"></service>`

Check the package name of your `TestService`class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind your activity with your service when your activity starts. To make this happen, your service must contain a Binder which the activity will use.
For more information, please check out the [Android Dev Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

**Service**

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
    LocalService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```